# category and subcategory display level wise

Tags: php, categories, multi-level

Please solve it with database .
https://prnt.sc/gp6x27 (please click here for clear view)

i am using database referrar_id (random number not 0 for parent id https://prnt.sc/gp6z0g) . need output like this screenshot

I am working on multilevel marketing on php
Below is exiting database structure (look like) (in screen1 ) but i need display like screen2

Note : its dynamic if more subcategory then level increase and i am using parent key like in4907422 (it random number)

(screen1 below)

computer
 -hardware
 --mouse
 --keyboard
 -software
 --php
 ---core  php
 ---magento
 ---opencart
 --java
shoes
 -Nike
 --Red
 --White
 -Puma
 -Addas
 -Reebok
Clothes
 -men
 --shirt
 --t'shirt
 -women

(screen2 below)
(1 level)
  computer
  shoes
  clothes
(2 level)
hardware
software
Nike
Puma
Addas
Reebok
men
women
(3 level)
mouse
php
java
red
white
shirt'shirt
(4 level)
magento
opencart

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format question properly and add screenshots.

Comment: please check i edited

Comment: more clear (https://prnt.sc/gp73tu) Gaip Id is foreign key

Answer (score 0):

you have two solutions here.

1. If you are known to the number to categories and there respective depth like category > sub category >> sub sub category

then you can make different table with foreign keys.

2. Create a categories table with following fields

   1. id
   2. name
   3. parent_id // nullable

here 1st level of categories will have no parent id, but the rest will have you can go as deeper as you like.